# FFMPEG xfade and acrossfade not working properly when used in combination

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, transition, fade, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to merge videos with transition effects. I am using [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) v5.1 android wrapper which is using ffmpeg v5.1.2 internally. When I use xfade and acrossfade in combination, the output video and audios are out of sync. Sometimes resultant video finishes first and sometimes audio finishes first.

Here is the sample command:

```
 -i "input1.mp4"    // 1080x1920, 6132 milliseconds,
 -i "input2.mp4"    // 1080x808,  4808 milliseconds
 -i "input3.mp4"    // 1280x720,  5399 milliseconds
 
 -filter_complex " 
 
 [0:v] scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[blurcanvas0]; 
 [0:v] scale=1080.0:1920.0:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled0]; 
 [blurcanvas0][scaled0] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[part0]; 
 
 [1:v] scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[blurcanvas1]; 
 [1:v] scale=1280.0:957.62964:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled1]; 
 [blurcanvas1][scaled1] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[part1]; 
 
 [2:v] scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[blurcanvas2]; 
 [2:v] scale=1280.0:720.0:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled2]; 
 [blurcanvas2][scaled2] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[part2];  
 
 [part0][part1] xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=2:offset=5.132[transition0]; 
 [transition0][part2] xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=2:offset=8.940001[transition1];    
 
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=2[afade0];
 [afade0][2:a]acrossfade=d=2[afade1] " 
 
 -vsync passthrough -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
 -map [transition1] -map [afade1] -preset ultrafast  "output.mp4"
```

Basically, the script takes videos of different resolutions and formats, scales them to the maximum size respecting the aspect ratio, adds a blurred background to extra space, and then joins the individual parts using a transition effect. Then audios are joined using acrossfade filter with the same transition duration as used in videos.

As per xfade requirements, script is converting videos to the same resolution and format yuv420p, changing fps to 30, and setting the timebase using settb=AVTB. All the requirements are met but the resultant video and audio are not synced. Any hint what is the missing part here?

### Edit:

As per @kesh reply, here is the updated command which has no impact:

```
-i "input1.mp4" -i "input2.mp4" -i "input3.mp4" -filter_complex " 

[0:v]scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[canvas0]; 
[0:v] scale=1080.0:1920.0:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled0]; 
[canvas0][scaled0] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[overlay0];

[1:v]scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[canvas1]; 
[1:v] scale=1280.0:957.62964:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled1]; 
[canvas1][scaled1] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[overlay1];

[2:v]scale=w=1280:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable, boxblur=40[canvas2]; 
[2:v] scale=1280.0:720.0:force_original_aspect_ratio=disable[scaled2]; 
[canvas2][scaled2] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)*0.5:(main_h-overlay_h)*0.5, settb=AVTB, format=yuv420p,fps=30[overlay2];  

[overlay0][overlay1] xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=2:offset=5.132[transition0]; 
[transition0][overlay2] xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=2:offset=8.940001[transition1];

[0:a]asettb=AVTB[audio0]; 
[1:a]asettb=AVTB[audio1]; 
[2:a]asettb=AVTB[audio2];    
[audio0][audio1]acrossfade=d=2[afade0]; 
[afade0][audio2]acrossfade=d=2[afade1]"

-vsync passthrough -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map [transition1] -map [afade1] -preset ultrafast  "output.mp4"
```

Comment: how about adding the audio counterpart `asettb` to the audio streams? Also, why `offset` in `xfade`s but not for `acrossfade`s? (ok, no `offset` in `acrossfade`, what happens if you remove the `offset`s?)

Comment: If I remove offset, the transition starts at time=0 of first video of xfade which will be definitely not the desired output. I have added asettb and added the updated command output in question which had no impact and video and audio are again out of sync. Please review.